# Ubuntu moving grub

Tags: ubuntu, partitioning, grub2, boot-partition

I need to expand partition with Ubuntu, but in the middle of the drive there is a boot partition. I tried using GParted but there's no option of realocating the grub2. I found some information on using Boot Repair, but I have not seen any option of locating the grub in a chosen place on a drive.

Question: How to safely move the boot loader.

[image: GParted screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

Instead of moving it I think it would be better to boot from a live install disk and reinstall grub. Here is the official ubuntu documentation on how to do it

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing

In high level summary, you should boot into a live distro, mount all your partitions, and run 'grub2-install /dev/sdX'

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It worked!